# Settings of Manufacturing is not displayed values correctly - Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm getting issue with Settings of Manufacturing is not displayed correctly while it's working fine on other modules likes Sales, CRM..

ie: I change Time Range to Monthly then Save, Setting is still displayed with default value (Weekly) while value in database is month

[image]

[image]

Comment: how many companies do you have in the db? did you already save the settings and refresh the page? week it's the default value of that field in the company

Comment: @aekis.dev: only 1 company, I tried to change the value and saves many times but the same view is displayed

Comment: I see, seems that it's something that will needs to be debugged and your environment in order to see what else it's messing with that feature